# Trigger 'mousestop' event to dynamically inserted element?

Tags: jquery, mousemove

I'm using the following plugin: https://github.com/richardscarrott/jquery-mousestop-event

I have one element which is injected dynamically into DOM using JavaScript, and I want to attach 'mousemove' event to this element:

```
$(document).on('mousestop', '.zoomImg', function(e) {
       // code goes here
});
```

This doesn't work, any suggestions?

Regards, Chris

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind an event to an element unless it exists in the DOM, so you'll need to do the binding after you're *sure* it exists. Remember that JavaScript is asynchronous and has function scope, so if you bind the event in the same function that injects the element, it should work.

```
function injectElement() {
  // Inject the element
  ...
  // Bind the event
  ...
}
```

Comment: are you sure, I thought the .on() should capture the event bubbling?

Comment: The second parameter of `.on()` is just a filter, it doesn't actually trigger anything when a new element is injected.

Comment: true for this plugins custom event 'mousestop', but should work for regular javascript events